# How to wait for MongoDB results in multiple nested loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to load a certain page from my website only after the data is loaded from the database. However, it prints the results too early, giving an empty array, and it doesn't group the names at all. I believe this may be solved with async and await functions or callbacks, but I'm new to those and despite what I've searched, I still can't find the solution. So far, I've just been messing around with wrapping certain loops or functions in async functions and awaiting them. Other solutions have been focused on one .find() or other loop. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Routes.js:

```
app.get("/test", async (req, res) => {
    var result = [];

    users.findById(mongo.ObjectID("IDString"), async (err, res) => {
        result = await res.getGroups(users, messages);
    });

    console.log(result);
    //this should print [["name1"]["name1", "name2"],["name3", "name1"]]

    res.redirect("/");
});
```

getGroups:

```
UserSchema.methods.getGroups = async function(users, messages) {
    var result = [];
    await messages.find({Group: this._id}, (err, group) => {
        for(var i = 0; i < group.length; i++){
            var members = group[i].Group;
            var subArray = [];

            members.forEach((memberID) => {
                users.findById(memberID, (err, req) => {
                    console.log(req.name);
                    subArray.push(req.name);
                    console.log(subArray);
                });
            });

            //After function finishes:
            console.log(subArray);
            result.push(subArray);
            subArray = [];
        }
    });
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first code snippet, you must set

```
console.log(result);
    //this should print [["name1"]["name1", "name2"],["name3", "name1"]]

res.redirect("/");
```

in the callback function of `findById`. Like this:

```
app.get("/test", async (req, res) => {
    var result = [];

    users.findById(mongo.ObjectID("IDString"), async (err, res) => {
        result = await res.getGroups(users, messages);

        console.log(result);
        //this should print [["name1"]["name1", "name2"],["name3", "name1"]]

        res.redirect("/");
    });
});
```

This is because of asynchronous nature of Javascript. Read the article below

https://medium.com/better-programming/is-javascript-synchronous-or-asynchronous-what-the-hell-is-a-promise-7aa9dd8f3bfb

If you want to use async/await paradigm, you can write this code like this:

app.get("/test", async (req, res) => {
    var result = [];

```
result = await users.findById(mongo.ObjectID("IDString"));

console.log(result);
//this should print [["name1"]["name1", "name2"],["name3", "name1"]]

res.redirect("/");
```

});

In your second code snippet, you should use await OR callback. Just as explained above.